# ascx control not triggering javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

My .ascx has below pieces

```
function confirmationDelete()
   {     
        var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this target");
        if (r == true) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        } 
    }


<asp:Button ID="btnDeleteTarget" runat="server" Text="Delete Target"  CssClass="btnDeleteTargetClass"  ValidationGroup="validateformgroup" CausesValidation="true"   OnClick="btnDeleteTarget_Click"  Visible="False" />
```

ascx.cs has below line

```
btnDeleteTarget.OnClientClick = "return confirmationDelete()";
```

I am still not getting confirmation prompt. page just refreshes. What am i doing wrong?

tried putting breakpoint in developer toolbar, but its not calling my JS function.

Comment: asp:Button or asp:HyperLink ?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

In your ***.ascx**:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDeleteTarget" runat="server" Text="Delete Target" CssClass="btnDeleteTargetClass" ValidationGroup="validateformgroup" CausesValidation="true" OnClick="btnDeleteTarget_Click" Visible="False" />
```

in your **.cs C#** :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     if (!IsPostBack)
     {
         btnDeleteTarget.Attributes["Onclick"] = "return confirm('Do you want Delete ?')";          
     }
}

protected void btnDeleteTarget_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Validate();
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
       //Delete all
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this within your Buttons OnClientClick Attribute:

```
OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');"
```

This would be your code:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDeleteTarget" runat="server" Text="Delete Target" CssClass="btnDeleteTargetClass" ValidationGroup="validateformgroup" CausesValidation="true" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');" Visible="False" />
```

Comment: No Luck. I know this should work, but somehow its not triggering javascript. not sure whats going wrong :(

Comment: Really curious! I have copied this piece of code from a project which i developed some weeks ago and it works fine. Hm, could you remove your line in the CS file `btnDeleteTarget.OnClientClick = "return confirmationDelete()";` and put instead my code in the OnClientClick Attribute on the .aspx page?